# Total delay of virtual circuit switching?

Tags: switching, layer2, packet-path, virtual

We know that virtual circuit switching(VCS) has both features of circuit switching and datagram switching. It uses connection oriented path but may or may not dedicated that means resources may or may not allocated in advance. As well since it's packet switching again here the store and forward approach is used. It works in 3 steps:

- connection establishment(C.E.)
- data transfer
- connection termination(C. T.)

So if there are n switches between sender and receiver the total delay should be : C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) +n(T_q+T_pro) + C. T, where T_t,T_p,T_q,T_pro are transmission time, propagation time, queueing delay, processing delay.

But  many websites saying total time is C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) + C. T. We know that it's store and forward technique , so must consider transmission time, propagation time, queueing delay, processing delay for every node. So what is right?

Comment: "but **may or may not** dedicated that means resources **may or may** not allocated in advance". Then each of the formulas **may or may** not be correct ;) Especially queueing delay **may or may not** be a factor.

Comment: @Effie virtual circuit works in layer2 or layer3 or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since it's packet switching again here the store and forward approach is used.

Not necessarily. While buffering is a fundamental property of forwarding nodes in packet-switched networks, cut-through forwarding is quite possible, whether it's plain packet switching or virtual circuit.

Using cut-through forwarding, the effective transmission (serialization) delay for an intermediate/forwarding node is not a whole packet but reduced to the portion required for the forwarding decision.

Also, transmission and reception can generally overlap, so both of those formulas are largely generalized and not really acurate.

Comment: what does mean of reception?

Comment: if i use cut-through then this formula C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) + C. T. is roughly correct. And if we store and forward then this formula C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) +n(T_q+T_pro) + C. T would be correct? Am I right?

Comment: *n* is the number of packets? Where's the number of hops?

Comment: n is number of switch/hops between sender and receiver.

Comment: if we use store and forward then this formula C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) +n(T_q+T_pro) + C. T would be roughly correct?  I don't want exactly correct.

Comment: what does it mean "transmission and reception can generally overlap, "?

Comment: When a packet's first bit clocked out, it propagates along the medium and then is clocked in on the next hop. When that happens, later bits from the same packet might still be clocked out (if the propagation delay is smaller than the serialization delay). With cut through, the very same packet can start to clock out while the previous hop hasn't even finished transmitting.

Comment: if I don't consider transmission and reception case, if we use store and forward then this formula C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) +n(T_q+T_pro) + C. T would be roughly correct?

Comment: are you looking for the exam answer or are you looking for an understanding?

Comment: @effie I am understanding for both.

Comment: Sorry, all *certification, educational and homework* questions are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: if you want to understand, processing delay may or may not be negligible and queueing delay may or may not be an issue, depending on whether interfaces can have different speeds or not, resources are actually reservated or not, is it possible to preemt packet transmission or not. If the medium is multiaccess contention medium also T_p is variable. And finally sending system may have queueing delay as well.

Comment: There is just no correct formula, there are models that allow to calculate stuff, which apply with various degree of correctness to each concrete virtual circuit system.

Comment: And your question lists relevant properties of the system, especially with respect to queueing delay as "may or may not" be there.

Comment: @Effie if I consider queueing delay and processing delay then my formula C.E + (n+1)(T_t +T_p) +n(T_q+T_pro) + C. T  will be correct?

Comment: Transmission/serialization delay usually overlap with current protocols, as explained above, so that's only once. Propagation times vary with distance, you can't just multiple them (unless you've got an average but then there's no point). You're formula is too theoretical/academic to be on-topic here, sorry.

Comment: @Zac67 virtual circuit works in layer2 or layer3 or both?

Comment: *Virtual circuit* is a general concept that may be implemented in various layers. *Switched virtual circuit* (SVC) usually refers to ATM which implements layers 1-3, with SVC providing functionality on top of that between L3 and L4, but it doesn't stick to the OSI model really.

Comment: @Zac67 "ATM which implements layers 1-3 with SVC providing functionality on top of that "--- means provide functionality up to layer7?

Comment: I have clarified the comment somewhat.

Comment: @Zac67 one thing don't understand SVC how give functionality on top of layer3 because it has limit layer3 header, so how to give functionality above it? You mean information passed from layer3 to above? Is it correct?

Comment: @Zac67 one final question is that virtual circuit switching  could do layer3 Packetization and layer2 framing ?